# Text overlapping issue in Close Vote dialog box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is a design issue with Close Vote dialog box.

[image]

As we can see, there is text overlapping.

Browser: Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: This probably belongs on the mother meta, I've noticed this as well on physics.SE today.

Comment: Firefox user (mainly) here : same problem, with Opera too (Edge = ok)

Comment: @JMac I didn't notice this on Movies & TV and SO. Maybe it is an issue on some sites.

Comment: It's on ELU as well. Not on my PC though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows status-completed on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301503/309993) and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357243/5832912), so hopefully, it will be reflected here soon.

Comment: Yep, it's done.